# jQuery complex selector with multiple classes in single element

Tags: jquery

I'm having some issues using jquery to wrap an  block around a  tag, I think the biggest problem I am having is with the jquery selector, but I'm very new to jquery so I'm not sure where exactly the problem is.

I have the following html

```
<section class="flexslider shop">
    <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="flex-prev">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="flex-next">Next</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I need to use jquery to wrap a  tag around each  tag and also insert a new li element between the two existing, the end result after the jquery has made its modifications should be the following:

```
<section class="flexslider shop">
    <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
        <li>
            <i class="icon-circle-arrow-left">
                <a href="#" class="flex-prev">Previous</a>
            </i>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="icon-zoom-in">
                <a href="#" id="nav-zoom-in"></a>
            </i>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right">
                <a href="#" class="flex-next">Next</a>
            </i>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

any help that could be given is greatly appreciated. I searched for hours but could not figure out how to get jquery of this complexity working. Also, all of this needs to happen once the page has loaded fully, there are no other triggers than that though.

---

Update

I now have it semi working with the help of some of you, this is what I have so far and it works as it should, the problem is the selectors in the jquery are not specific enough, and I can not modify the html as it is being generated by a jquery plugin, so I am attempting to modify that plugin after the fact by using this little script you all are helping me with, what I have so far is the following:

The script in question generates the following html:

```
 <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
     <li>
         <a href="#" class="flex-prev">Previous</a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="#" class="flex-next">Next</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

I added the  tag with a class in order to target it through jquery, so the html now looks as follows:

```
<section class="flexslider shop">
    <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="flex-prev">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="flex-next">Next</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

The jquery I'm using now is the following, and it does as needed, but is not specific enough since I have more than one slider on the page.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".flex-direction-nav li:last").before('<li><i class="icon-zoom-in"><a href="#" id="nav-zoom-in"></a></i></li>');
    $(".flex-prev").wrap('<i class="icon-circle-arrow-left" />');
    $(".flex-next").wrap('<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right" />');
});
```

This is now generating the proper html output and is working as it is supposed to, however I need it to specifically target the ul class="flex-direction-nav" that is inside of section class="flexslider shop" since there is more than one ul class="flex-direction-nav" on the page

Comment: note that `i` is a presentational markup. You should use `em` (emphasis) or (in your case) CSS.

Comment: Look into the `.wrap`, `.addClass` and `.removeClass` methods.

Comment: Do you just want to add an <li> tag between Previous and Next links?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm using the <i> tag because the class for it modifies the font, it works with <em> as well, I just wrote the css using <i>

Comment: @RavinderSingh I need to insert the <li> block between the two existing <li>'s and also wrap the existing <a> tags with the <i> tag.

Comment: @user2134638 don't use `<i>` just to modify the visual style. CSS is a language better suited to define the style.

Comment: @user2134638, by the way on which event you want to perform this action?

Comment: @RavinderSingh no event, just the window loading, I'm using this as essentially a hack to modify the navigation created from a plugin.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and suggestions, I have updated the original post to provide an update and the final problem I am running into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I don't recommend using the `<i>` tag. It tells the browser how something *should look like*, not what it *is*. `<i>` is presentational, not semantic. The `<em>` tag (emphasis) is better (semantic), but in your case, you should probably just add `.flexslider li a{font-style: italic}` to your CSS.

But let's assume the extra tag is neccessary so that the elements are found by a plugin whose source code cannot be changed.

---

> I need it to specifically target the ul class="flex-direction-nav" that is inside of section class="flexslider shop"

This should achieve the desired output from your example:

```
$("section.flexslider.shop ul.flex-direction-nav").each(function(){
  $(".flex-prev", this).wrap('<i class="icon-circle-arrow-left">')
  $(".flex-next", this).wrap('<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right">')
  .before(
    '<li><i class="icon-zoom-in"><a href="#" id="nav-zoom-in"></a></i></li>
  ')
)};
```

I have used `each` so that the selector `section.flexslider.shop ul.flex-direction-nav` is only queried once. This reduces the amount of code required and it (hopefully) improves the performance. Passing `this` as the second argument to jQuery limits the scope of the previous selector.

An alternative would be to use `section.flexslider.shop ul.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev` and `section.flexslider.shop ul.flex-direction-nav .flex-next` directly as the two selectors, without selecting `section.flexslider.shop ul.flex-direction-nav` first. Note, however, the amount of code required. Also note a less specific selector (say, `.flex-direction-nav ...`) would likely suffice.

Comment: the extra tag is needed, also this works, however I need the jquery selector to specify the section and ul tags, otherwise it will grab to many entries, it is one specific set of tags in the document that I need to modify, not all that match what is selected thus far, Thank you so far though

Comment: @user2134638 you can always replace an extra tag with an extra class for the purposes of selection; however, it seems like `.flexslider a` would do, and you don't even need to add a class.

Comment: I have more than one flexslider class on the page, I only want to target a specific one, not both. thats why the section is there to give jquery something else to target.

Comment: @user2134638 perhaps the selectors should be `section .flex-prev` and `section .flex-next`, or something in that style? I can't tell which selectors are specific enough for your code without seeing your HTML. Perhaps you should add an ID or a class?

Comment: I've updated my original post to modify the appropriate changes made and hopefully explain better. thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @user2134638 updated to reflect your requirements for the selector

Comment: Thank you, this correctly does what I need it to with the appropriate specificity to not select other ul's in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Please check 
http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/
&
http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

```
$('<li><i class="icon-zoom-in"><a href="#" id="nav-zoom-in"></a></i></li>').insertBefore('.flex-next').parent();

$('<i class="icon-circle-arrow-left">').insertBefore('.flex-prev');

$('</i>').insertAfter('.flex-prev');

$('<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right">').insertBefore('.flex-next');$('</i>').insertAfter('.flex-next');
```

It will solve your problem.

But one thing must consider, you can achieve this target by using addClass & removeClass. It depends upon your choice. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far, I've updated my original post to modify the appropriate changes made and hopefully explain better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var zoom = $('<li><i class="icon-zoom-in"><a href="#" id="nav-zoom-in"></a></i></li>');

$('.flex-next').wrap('<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right" />');
$('.flex-prev').wrap('<i class="icon-circle-arrow-left" />').parents('li').after(zoom);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/duukU/)

Comment: I've updated my original post to modify the appropriate changes made and hopefully explain better. thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flexslider .flex-direction-nav li:last").before('<li><i class="icon-zoom-in"><a href="#" id="nav-zoom-in"></a></i></li>');
    $(".flexslider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-prev").wrap('<i class="icon-circle-arrow-left" />');
    $(".flexslider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-next").wrap('<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right" />');
});
```

Comment: this works, however I need the jquery selector to specify the section and ul tags, otherwise it will grab to many entries, it is one specific set of tags in the document that I need to modify, not all that match what is selected thus far, Thank you so far though

Comment: So tell me on which event you want to do this?

Comment: no event, just the window load, I'm using this as a hack to modify the navigation created by a plugin.

Comment: this still does not select only the one flex slider, I have the section tag in place specifically for targeting the correct flex-direction-nav class since I have more than one on the page.

Comment: I've updated my original post to modify the appropriate changes made and hopefully explain better. thank you for your help so far.